# Is it safe to remove all these packages?

Tags: release-freya, apt, package-management

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-horai-umefont git git-man glib-networking:i386 gnome-exe-thumbnailer
  gnome-session-canberra i965-va-driver:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386
  libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libatspi2.0-0:i386
  libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386
  libcdr-0.0-0 libcmis-0.4-4 libcolord1:i386 liberror-perl libexif12:i386
  libftgl2 libgd3:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgegl-0.2-0 libgif4:i386
  libglu1-mesa:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port10:i386
  libgraphite2-3:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386
  libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libhdb9-heimdal
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386
  libieee1284-3:i386 libindicate5 libjasper1:i386 libjson-glib-1.0-0:i386
  libkdc2-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386
  libltdl7:i386 libmowgli2 libmpg123-0:i386 libmspub-0.0-0 libnoise-core0
  libntdb1 libodbc1:i386 libopenal1:i386 liborcus-0.6-0 libosmesa6
  libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386
  libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpcap0.8:i386
  libpixman-1-0:i386 libprojectm2 libproxy1:i386 libqxt-core0 libqxt-gui0
  librest-0.7-0:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386
  libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0
  libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 libsoup2.4-1:i386 libsqlheavy0.1-0 libtimezonemap1
  libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386 libva-drm1:i386
  libva-glx1 libva-x11-1:i386 libva1:i386 libvdpau1:i386 libvisio-0.0-0
  libvncclient0 libvpx1:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386
  libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwpd-0.9-9 libwpg-0.2-2 libwps-0.2-2 libx265-59
  libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386
  libxinerama1:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386
  linux-headers-3.19.0-26 linux-headers-3.19.0-26-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-26-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-26-generic
  linux-lts-xenial-tools-4.4.0-21 linux-tools-4.4.0-21-generic
  ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 p11-kit-modules:i386 python-ntdb sbsigntool
  secureboot-db ttf-dejavu-core va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-va-driver:i386
  wine-gecko2.21 wine-gecko2.21:i386 wine-gecko2.34 wine-gecko2.34:i386
  wine-mono0.0.8 wine-mono4.5.4 xfonts-mathml
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

On a couple of occasions using ubuntu-based systems a similar message with a lot of dependencies incited me to break my system.

Comment: So did my answer work ?

Comment: @SuiciDoga - yes. confirmed

Comment: Also is your PC UEFI ?

Comment: @SuiciDoga - bios

Comment: Ok, I was just asking since the `secureboot-db` package is installed on my laptop since it is UEFI.The package is not needed for Legacy DOS BIOS systems or if you are booting with CSM or legacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you do last?

This can happen when you remove a 32-bit package on a 64-bit system.After that the system does not need these libraries and will add them to **autoremove**.

If it is that then safely remove (but create a system snapshot before so you can restore if anything breaks)

Comment: They are there since long time ago, I cannot tell what happened. I want an answer about the packages listed there. Do they include system files? I

Comment: @cipricus Their just 32-bit libraries that you won't need on a 64-bit system if you don't have 32-bit apps installed. So you should be able to remove them safely (but create a image of the system before)

Comment: @cipricus Do you have WINE installed ? These packages are installed by WINE so it should be normal if you have uninstalled WINE

Comment: that's it then. I have uninstalled Wine. Therefore  `apt-get autoremove` should be safe

Comment: @cipricus Yes but do create a system image (you don't have to)